# .NET Core Worker with EF DB Context cache

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-6.0

I have a Worker that is using a shared library with services and repositories for data import.

This configuration for the Program.cs:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    var configuration = hostContext.Configuration;

    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

    services.AddSingleton<IBenefitAppService, BenefitAppService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IBenefitRepository, BenefitRepository>();
    
    services.AddSingleton<IBeneficiaryAppService, BeneficiaryAppService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IBeneficiaryRepository, BeneficiaryRepository>();

    services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(configuration.GetSection(DatabaseSettings.Section));

    services.AddDbContext<EntityContext>(opts =>
    {
        var settingsSection = configuration.GetSection(DatabaseSettings.Section);
        var dbSettings = new DatabaseSettings();

        settingsSection.Bind(dbSettings);

        var connString = dbSettings.GetConnectionString();

        opts.UseSqlServer(connString);
    });

    //services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog());
})
.UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)
//.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
.Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

This is the Service that calls for the repository:

```
public async Task<Beneficiary> Create(Beneficiary beneficiary)
{
    try
    {
      var createdBeneficiary = await _beneficiaryRepository.Create(beneficiary);

      return createdBeneficiary;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is SqlException sqlException && sqlException.Number == 2601)
    {
      _logger.LogError(ex, "Create: Erro ao criar associado por CPF duplicado");

      throw new APIException("CPF informado já está em uso por outro associado", 409);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is not APIException)
    {
      _logger.LogError(ex, "Create: Erro ao criar associado");
      throw;
    }
}
```

The code responsible for insertion on the database is simple:

```
public virtual async Task<T> Create<T>(T register)
{
    _context.Add(register);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return register;
}
```

This is the entity:

```
public class Beneficiary : BenefitedBase
{
    public string CallName { get; set; }
    public string SocialName { get; set; }
    public string TreatmentPronoun { get; set; }
    public string BadgeNumber { get; set; }
    public string AssociateCode { get; set; }
    public int GenderId { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public int JobDescriptionId { get; set; }
    public JobDescription JobDescription { get; set; }
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public Plan Plan { get; set; }
    public int OperationBaseId { get; set; }
    public OperationBase OperationBase { get; set; }
    public int AircraftModelId { get; set; }
    public AircraftModel AircraftModel { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CompanyStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AssociationStartDate { get; set; }
    public string ANACRegistration { get; set; }
    public string CHTRegistration { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CMACertificateExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CAMGracePeriodEndDate { get; set; }
    #nullable enable
    public int? BankId { get; set; }
    #nullable restore
    public Bank Bank { get; set; }
    public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }
    public string BankAgencyNumber { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public int BeneficiaryTypeId { get; set; }
    public BeneficiaryType BeneficiaryType { get; set; }

    public List<BeneficiaryBenefit> BeneficiaryBenefits { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is, my Beneficiary entity has a CPF unique validation at the DB using Indexes. I did 2 runs of import:

1. I have a beneficiary with CPF registered and try to import a
   repeated one, exception is thrown and all is good
2. I changed the beneficiary CPF on the database and the worker
   still gets the same error of duplicated CPF.

The same issue happened with two other entities with different indexes and fields. What could be causing this behavior? I have already tried to close the VS, restart the application, change the lifetime type of DI and nothing solves this.

I`m using .NET Core 6, SQL DB and EF. All on the latest version.

Comment: Don't use `AddSingleton`. Also, it probably helps to show the entity classes. And the code that calls `Create`. It's important to know the content of `register`.

Comment: @GertArnold I added the rest of the code, i have already tried with Singleton too and the same happens.

Comment: By default AddDbContext is at scope level. You other services are singleton. You may have DB concurrency issues. Try to set your service at Scope level

Comment: Then what is `document`?

Comment: @GertArnold Document is the CPF of the Beneficiary. It is an identifying document from the government.

Comment: @CyrilANDRE I changed the DI from ```AddSingleton``` to ```AddScoped``` and the same error occurred.